# Mongod 24 hour monitoring advertisement disable

Tags: mongodb

I've recently upgraded our open source mongodb version.

Now this wall of corporate text fills up my mobile ssh terminal every time I run mongo:

> Enable MongoDB's free! - 24 hour history only - cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
>       metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc). But we don't keep history over 24 hours.
>
> The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
>       and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
>       improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.
>
> To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
>
> To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()

I can't get rid of it because db.disableFreeMonitoring() doesn't persist between restarts. We shutdown the local servers because they aren't being used during nighttime.

Enviroment: Mongo version: 4.0.5, Debian

Answer (score 5):

Found the permanent solution in the mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#cloud.monitoring.free.state)

In /etc/mongod.conf write:

```
cloud:
  monitoring:
    free:
      state: "off"
```

Then run either

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
sudo service mongod restart
```

Honestly mongo, you should never be this persistent when pushing unwanted monetization features. It's bad enough it's enabled by default. You are after all, only a lovely opensource db service, just like mysql. - Sincerely Redis